# On minimum cardinality of generating sets of modules

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, set-theory, cardinals

Let $\alpha$ be an infinite cardinal. Let $M$ be an $R$-module with $\mu (M) < \alpha$ , where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of all submodules $N$ of $M$ such that $\mu (N) \ge \alpha$ . If $\mathcal F$ is non-empty, then does that imply that $\mathcal F$ has a maximal element ? (where $\mu (M)$ denotes the minimum cardinality among generating sets of $M$ )

The only place where I am stuck while applying Zorn's lemma is that I can't seem to conclude that every totally ordered subset of $\mathcal F$ has an upper bound w.r.t. inclusion. If $\alpha = \aleph_0$ , then I could easily conclude the upper bound because if every member a totally ordered collection $\{N_i\}$ is not finitely generated, then $\cup_i N_i$ is also not finitely generated. But I don't know what to do if we have a general infinte cardinal $\alpha$ .

Comment: Wasn't this posted on MathOverflow recently?

Comment: @AsafKaragila : No ... it was a similar looking but different post, by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a man with a hammer, everything looks like a nail, and following [another recent question of yours](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295577/cardinality-of-generating-sets-of-faithful-modules-over-integral-domain) on MathOverflow, I have a new hammer. Quite probably it's a bit of a sledgehammer for this question, and I'd be interested in easier examples.

I'll give an example of a cyclic module which has submodules that are not countably generated, but has no maximal such submodule, answering your question in the negative for $\alpha=\aleph_1$.

Let $W$ be a well-ordered set with the order type of $\aleph_\omega=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\aleph_n$, and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $w_n$ be the least element of $W$ such that the initial segment $\{w\in W\mid w<w_n\}$ has cardinality $\aleph_n$. Then $\{w_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable cofinal subset of $W$.

Let $\mathbb{Z}^W$ be the group of functions $W\to\mathbb{Z}$, ordered lexicographically using the well-order on $W$ (i.e., $f<g$ if and only if $f(w)<g(w)$ for the least $w\in W$ with $f(w)\neq g(w)$). Then $\mathbb{Z}^W$ is a totally ordered abelian group.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $f_n\in\mathbb{Z}^W$ be the function 
$$f_n(w)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }w=w_n\\
0&\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

For $0\neq f\in\mathbb{Z}^W$ let $d(f)\in W$ be the least $w\in W$ with $f(w)\neq0$. For some $n$, $w_n>d(f)$ and so if $f>0$ then $f_n\leq f$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

By a theorem of Krull, every totally ordered abelian group is the value group of some valuation domain. Let $R$ be a valuation domain with value group $\mathbb{Z}^W$, and $\nu:R\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{Z}^W$ the associated valuation.

Recall that in a valuation domain $R$, if $x,y\in R$ with $\nu(x)\leq \nu(y)$ then $x$ divides $y$, or equivalently the principal ideal generated by $x$ contains the principal ideal generated by $y$.

Ideals of $R$ correspond to upwards closed subsets $U$ of non-negative elements of $\mathbb{Z}^W$ (i.e., subsets such that if $u\in U$ and $u<v$ then $v\in U$), with $I_U=\{r\in R\mid \nu(r)\in U\}\cup\{0\}$ the ideal corresponding to $U$. [Certainly $I_U$ is an ideal. Conversely, if $I$ is any ideal and $U=\left\{\nu(x)\mid 0\neq x\in I\right\}$ then $I=I_U$.]

The unique maximal ideal $I_{U_{>0}}$ is the ideal corresponding to the set $U_{>0}$ of strictly positive elements of $\mathbb{Z}^W$, and is countably generated by any set $\{r_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of elements of $R$ with $\nu(r_n)=f_n$, since if $0<f\in\mathbb{Z}^W$ we have seen that there is some $n$ with $f_n\leq f$, and so $U_{>0}$ is the upwards closure of $\left\{f_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$.

We'll take $M=R$ and suppose that $I_U$ is a maximal uncountably generated ideal of $R$. Since $I_{U_{>0}}$ is countably generated, there must be some strictly positive element $g\in\mathbb{Z}^W$ that is not in $U$. Let $w=d(g)$, choose $0<n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $w<w_n$, and let $V$ be the set of positive elements $f\in\mathbb{Z}^W$ for which $d(f)<w_n$. Then $V$ is an upwards closed subset of $\mathbb{Z}^W$ that properly contains $U$, and so $I_U$ is a proper subideal of $I_V$.

But $I_V$ is not countably generated, since $\aleph_n$ does not have countable cofinality. If $\{s_k\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable subset of $I_V$ then there is an element $s\in I_V$ with $d\left(\nu(s)\right)>d(\left(\nu(s_k)\right)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and so $s$ is not in the ideal generated by $\{s_k\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: When you say $W$ is a well-ordered set of order type $\aleph_{\omega} $ , what do you mean ? Shouldn't the order type be an ordinal number ?

Comment: @users It is an ordinal. A cardinal is usually defined to be the smallest ordinal of a given cardinality, so $\aleph_\omega$ is the smallest ordinal that has larger cardinality than $\aleph_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: could you please elaborate why the unique maximal ideal is generated by any set $\{r_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ with $v(r_n)=f_n$ ? And why are ideals determined by Upwards closed subsets of non-negative elements of the group ? Why Upwards closed ?

Comment: @users I've added some explanations.

Comment: thanks .. I do see what is $U$ , but what do you mean by "Upwards closed " (sorry if I am being stupid , but I don't understand this point ... )

Comment: @users Sorry, I just mean that if $x$ is in there, and $x<y$, then $y$ is also in there. When I have a minute I’ll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: thanks, ok , no problem ... just another question : you showed that we may not find maximal element when $\alpha = \aleph_1$ ... what happens for $\alpha > \aleph_1$ ? Does some $\alpha > \aleph_0$ work ?

Comment: @users I think that exactly the same example works for $\alpha=\aleph_k$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$: Towards the end of the proof, where I choose $0<n$ with $w<w_n$, just choose $n\geq k$ with $w<w_n$ instead. And probably you can adjust the example for larger $\alpha$ by replacing $\aleph_\omega$ with a larger singular cardinal.

Comment: When you explain why the maximal ideal is generated by $\{r_n\}$, what do you mean by $f_n \le n$ ? Also, you say $I_U$ be the maximal uncountable generated ideal ... my question is : does $R$ at all have any ideal which is not countably generated ? (I wanted my family $\mathcal F$ to be non-empty ... )

Comment: the contradiction you arrive at the last stage might well mean that $R$ has no ideal with $\mu (I)\ge \aleph_1$ at all ... that wouldn't serve as an example then since I want my family to be non-empty

Comment: @users Sorry, “$f_n\leq n$” was a typo. I meant “$f_n\leq f$”. I’ve corrected it. The maximal ideal is generated by $\{r_n\}$ because for any $r$ in the maximal ideal, there is some $r_n$ with $\nu(r_n)<\nu(r)$, and so $r$ is in the ideal generated by $r_n$. The ideal consisting of all $r$ with $\nu(r)>f_1$ is not countably generated.

Comment: @users The key fact is that there is no countable set of ordinals strictly less than $\aleph_1$ whose supremum is $\aleph_1$, but there *is* a countable set of ordinals strictly less than (the larger ordinal) $\aleph_\omega$ whose supremum is $\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: @users Sorry, for the uncountably generated ideal in a previous comment I meant the set of $r$ with $d(\nu(r))<w_1$, not $\nu(r)>f_1$.

Comment: Thanks ... two more questions ... (1) why is it that given a $w_n$, the set of all positive $f\in \mathbb Z^W$ with $d(f)< w_n$ an Upward closed subset of $\mathbb Z^W$ ? 

(2) given a $w_n$ you claim that the ideal $I=\{0\} \cup \{r\in R : d(v(r))<w_n \}$ is not countably generated. To prove that you say if $\{s_n\}$ is any countable subset of $I$, then there is $s\in I$ with $d(v(s)) > d(v(s_n))$, why is it true ? Moreover in this case why is $s$ not in the ideal generated by $\{s_n\}$ ? ...

Comment: continued .... if $s$ is in the ideal generated by $\{s_n\}$ , then since $R$ is a Valuation ring, we have $s=rs_n$ for some $n$ and some $r\in R$, and then $v(s) \ge v(s_n)$, but I don't see why would it contradict $d(v(s)) > d(v(s_n))$ ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77750/discussion-between-jeremy-rickard-and-users).